# GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to sample maximum of nearby texels

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Is it possible to sample maximum value of nearby texels in `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` instead of `GL_LINEAR`/`GL_NEAREST` approximations, and, if so, how?

Comment: Look around [EXT_texture_filter_minmax](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_filter_minmax.txt)

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? When you say "sample maximum value" do you literally mean the maximum r, g, b within n texels? or do you just want to sample n texels from a sampler?

Comment: @Vallentin, well, currently I am using monochrome texture, so yes, I literally mean exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with 2x2 texels sample you could use [EXT_texture_filter_minmax](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_filter_minmax.txt) (as suggested by pleluron in comments).

If you have to perform sampling from more specific set of texels you could do it yourself in a shader by sampling texture multiple times and computing result as desired. Be sure to use nearest sampling if you do that.